# KeyPressed working on N95 but not woking on N86 etc

Tags: java, custom-controls, java-me, keypress

I have a customItem in my application and I am using keypressed event for it. Until now, I have been testing my application on N95 and it works perfectly there but the same keypressed event is not working on other nokia phones such as N86 and ExpressMusic. Does anybody know what the issue is.

Thanks and regards,
Ashish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a similar problem, fixed it by changing the to keyTyped instead of keyPressed.